# Conditionally assign Flux variable - syntax error

Tags: influxdb-2, fluxlang

I'm trying to conditionally assign a value to the variable START as part of a Flux query:

```
WINDOW = 1d
START = if WINDOW == 1d then today() else 2022-01-01
```

This results in the following error:

```
unsupported binary expression duration == duration
```

What is the correct syntax/approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it to string and then compare:

```
if string(v: WINDOW) == string(v: 1d) then today() else 2022-01-01
```